# How to grep for this pattern in Unix

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

I want to grep for this particular pattern. The pattern is as follows

```
**xMT123xMT123x**ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887
```

inside the file test.txt which has the following data

```
NNN**xMT123xMT123x**ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887_20140628.csv
```

I tried using grep "**xMT123xMT123x**ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887" test.txt but it's not returning anything. Please advice

EDIT:

Hi, basically i'm inside a loop and only sometimes i get files with this pattern. So currently im putting like grep "$i" test.txt which works in all the cases except when I have to encounter such patterns.

And I'm actually grepping for the exact file_number, file sequence.So if it says 123_29887 it will be 123_29887. Thanks.

Comment: Remember * is a meta character in regex indicating "zero or more". If you want to match a literal star character you have to backslash escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
grep -P "(?i)\*\*[a-z\d]+\*\*[a-z]+_\d+_\d+" somepath
```

- `(?i)` turns on case-insensitive mode
- `\*\*` matches the two opening stars
- `[a-z\d]+` matches letters and digits
- `\*\*` matches two more stars
- `[a-z]+` matches letters
- `_\d+_\d+` matches underscore, digits, underscore, digits

If you need to be more specific (for instance, you know that a group of digits always has three digits), you can replace parts of the expression: for instance, `\d+` becomes `\d{3}`

**Matching a Literal but Yet Unknown Pattern: `\Q` and `\E`**

If you receive literal patterns that you need to match, such as `**xMT123xMT123x**ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887`, the issue is that special regex characters such as `*` need to be escaped. If the whole string is a literal, we do this by escaping the whole string between `\Q` and `\E`:

```
grep -P "\Q**xMT123xMT123x**ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887\E" somepath
```

And in a loop, of course, you can build that regex programmatically by concatenating `\Q` and `\E` on both sides.

Comment: Hi, if im inside a loop where i get many different file patterns how do i handle .?? Is it posibble with a single grep statement .?

Comment: And I'm actually grepping for the exact file_number, file sequence.So if it says 123_29887 it will be 123_29887. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look. :)

Comment: Great, thanks for letting me know. See you next time! :)

Comment: Sure.. Was stuck with this actually :)

Comment: `grep -P` is fantastic. It lets you grep in Perl mode, so you can build some really nice regular expressions using full-featured syntax, including lookbehinds and all kinds of crazy stuff I won't bore you with. Really glad for you that you're unstuck! :) It would not have been fun to make rules to escape these characters one by one.

Comment: Hi zx just had one more doubt actually, The destination system is sending files with the pattern "NNN__xMT123xMT123x__ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887_20140628.csv" since they're not able to handle, but my source pattern still remains "**xMT123xMT123x**ABCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_123_29887". How can i grep this .?

Comment: You could change the grep pattern to this: `(?i)[*_]{2}[a-z\d]+[*_]{2}[a-z]+_\d+_\d+`